# Using functions to define virtual field values in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I want to do something like (all this code would be inside the Model, naturally):

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'description' => $this->fillDescription()
);

private function fillDescription() {
    $type = $this->data['type'];
    $quantity = $this->data['quantity'];
    switch($type) {
        case 'type A':
            'This should be a specific description for type A records and this record has quantity:'.$quantity;
            break;
        case 'type B':
            'This should be a specific description for type B records and this record has quantity:'.$quantity;
            break;
        etc...
    }
}
```

Is there any way **to do this in the model** or I'll really need to create this virtual field on the fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with virtual fields like so:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'description' => '
      CASE 
      WHEN type = "A" THEN CONCAT("quantity a description ", quantity)
      WHEN type = "B" THEN CONCAT("quantity b description ", quantity)
      WHEN type = "C" THEN CONCAT("quantity c description ", quantity)
      END
    '
);
```

I'm not super familiar with [MySQL `CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) but that should be what you're looking for.

If you want to do it using PHP in the model, do it when constructing the model:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    $this->virtualFields['description'] = $this->fillDescription();
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}

private function fillDescription() {
     $out = 'CASE';
     $out .= ' WHEN type = "A" THEN CONCAT("quantity a description ", quantity)';
     $out .= ' WHEN type = "B" THEN CONCAT("quantity a description ", quantity)';
     $out .= ' WHEN type = "C" THEN CONCAT("quantity a description ", quantity)';
     $out .= ' END';
     return $out;
}
```

If you need to perform logic against `quantity` or `type`, I suggest using `afterFind` instead.

Comment: +1 for being able to figure out what the OP was asking for for ;)